# Set i18n locale on fly on Nuxt3 Plugin

Tags: nuxtjs3, vue-i18n

I am using Nuxt 3.8.2 and @nuxtjs/i18n: 8.0.0

Although the language is being set properly from the plugin, I am getting this error whenever I am setting locale on NuxtPlugin:
`[nitro] [unhandledRejection] Error: [nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook, Nuxt middleware, or Vue setup function. This is probably not a Nuxt bug.`

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/i18n'
],
i18n: {
  locales: [
    { code: 'en', iso: 'en-IN', file: 'en.json', dir: 'ltr' },
    { code: 'hi', iso: 'hi-IN', file: 'hi.json', dir: 'ltr' }
  ],
  langDir: 'i18n/',
  strategy: 'no_prefix',
  lazy: true,
  detectBrowserLanguage: false,
  defaultLocale: 'en'
}
```

Plugin - **init.i18n.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
  const lang = 'hi'

  // method 1
  nuxtApp.vueApp.$nuxt.$i18n.setLocale(lang)

  // method 2
  const { $i18n } = nuxtApp as any
  $i18n.setLocale(lang)

  // method 3
  const app = useNuxtApp()
  app.$i18n.setLocale(lang)

  // All 3 methods work but give the same error. 
  // Can someone explain what's the difference in these methods
  // and which would be best suited for this use case?
})
```

I don't want to define the `domain` property in i18n because we have custom logic to figure out the user's language.

How to get rid of the error/warning? Will it cause a problem having said that we are running Nuxt in the SSR context?